# Create a "normal" ASP.NET page which depends on an Umbraco master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

Is it possible in Umbraco to create a normal webforms page which inherits the main Umbraco master page?

My client has a requirement for some complex functionality which needs to be done in a page outside the context of the CMS.

I wonder whether it's possible to fire up the Umbraco context manually from within the constructor of a "normal" page.  At the moment I just get the error:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at umbraco.item..ctor(IDictionary elements, IDictionary
>   attributes) at
>   umbraco.presentation.templateControls.ItemRenderer.GetFieldContents(Item
>   item) at
>   umbraco.presentation.templateControls.ItemRenderer.ParseMacros(Item
>   item) at umbraco.presentation.templateControls.Item.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at

thanks
Kris

Comment: Are you not able to perform the functionality using a User Control placed on a specific page?

Comment: Sure, but this leaves the possibility of the user deleting the host page inside the CMS.  The problem is that you end up clogging up the CMS with non-CMS pages.

Comment: And the other problem is, you cannot "script" the creation of CMS assets, therefore, when the overhead on deployment of functionality relies on manual config, this takes time and is error prone.  If I can just leave the CMS stuff out of the equation altogether then it would be a lot easier for stuff like this.

Comment: I suppose I could always create a separate non-Umbraco master page. Not ideal though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can achieve what you are asking;

The usual way to take a page out of the control of Umbraco is to use the web.config keys umbracoReservedUrls and umbracoReservedPaths - these are the keys installed with 4.11.1:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd" />
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
```

Secondly if your top level master page contains no umbraco items or macros or anything you can always switch to a masterpage during the Page PreInit event

```
protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "/umbraco/masterpages/default.master";
}
```

Or you could use the technique that @BeaverProj outlines.

**EDIT**

Looking at your comment I think that you can get at umbraco data without being in umbraco 'context'.  Add project references to cms.dll and businesslogic.dll (umbraco will have dropped them in the bin) and then you can use the umbraco framework without the wrapper controls.  For example the internal editMacro.aspx page uses the framework directly:

```
                <asp:DropDownList OnPreRender="AddChooseList" runat="server" ID="macroPropertyType"
                    DataTextFormatString="" DataTextField='macroPropertyTypeAlias' DataValueField="id"
                    DataSource='<%# GetMacroPropertyTypes()%>' SelectedValue='<%# ((umbraco.cms.businesslogic.macro.MacroPropertyType) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type")).Id %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately, my master page does contain Umbraco items.  I have decided to create a separate Non Umbraco master page which largely duplicates the Umbraco one.  I didn't want to duplicate functionality, but it seems like there's no other way.  (I thought maybe it would be possible to create a "fake" Umbraco context which would enable the Umbraco master page to work under a normal page).  thanks

Comment: I think you can (now I think of it) because Umbraco already does.  See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternate templates to reference a template directly without having a Content Page associated with it.

You can reference it in these ways:

http://www.yourdomain.com/page.aspx?altTemplate=templatename

http://www.yourdomain.com/page/templatename.aspx

That would prevent users from deleting the node.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

U can inherit from umbraco master pages specify your masterpages manually like this

`MasterPageFile="../masterpages/umbracoPage.Master"`

This works for an `.aspx` page where you are specifying this page in the `plugin directory`